# AWS CloudFormation function call fails: Fn::ImportValue must not depend on any resources, imported values, or Fn::GetAZs

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation template (mainVPC) that creates few Subnets in a VPC and exports the subnets with names "PrivateSubnetA", "PrivateSubnetB" ...
I have a different cloud formation template that creates DBSubnetGroup. I want to use "PrivateSubnetA", "PrivateSubnetB" as default values if user does not provide data. CloundFormation does not support imported values in parameters. So I put some default value (XXXX) and had a condition section to see if the user has provided some input

```
Conditions:
  userNotProvidedSubnetA: !Equals 
    - !Ref PrivateSubnetA
    - XXXX
  userNotProvidedSubnetB: !Equals 
    - !Ref PrivateSubnetB
    - XXXX
```

This helps me in figuring out if the user has provided data. Now I want to use default values, if the user has not provided values, else use user-provided values.
below is code for that

```
 DBSubnetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup'
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: RDS Aurora Cluster Subnet Group
      SubnetIds:
        - !If 
          - userNotProvidedSubnetA
          - Fn::ImportValue:
                !Sub  '${fmMainVpc}-PrivateSubnetA'
          - !Ref PrivateSubnetA
        - !If 
          - userNotProvidedSubnetB
          - Fn::ImportValue:
                !Sub '${fmMainVpc}-PrivateSubnetB'
          - !Ref PrivateSubnetB
```

This fails with the error "Template error: the attribute in Fn::ImportValue must not depend on any resources, imported values, or Fn::GetAZs".
ImportValue is not used anywhere else in the template.

Is there a way for using exported values as default values ( the default values cannot be hardcoded, they come as exported values from a run of another stack), while providing an option for the users to provide their own values (to create resources).

Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

This can also be caused by having a reference inside `Fn::ImportValue` to a parameter be misnamed. For example, if I have the following parameter `NetworkStackName` defined and I mis-reference it in the `Fn::ImportValue` statement (as `NetworkName`), I will get this error. I would need to change the `NetworkName` to match the value in Parameters, `NetworkStackName` to fix the error.

```
Parameters:
  NetworkStackName:
      Type: String
      Default: happy-network-topology
Resources:
  MySQLDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      Engine: MySQL
      DBSubnetGroupName:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${NetworkName}-DBSubnetGroup"
```

Comment: Likewise if you forget to import the value as a "Parameter"!

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem where I needed to get my artifact bucket name from my prerequisite stack,  I tried this:

```
Fn::ImportValue:
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactStore}/*'
```

turns out you can do this and it will work. Hope his helps someone out one day!

```
    - !Sub

        - 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*'

        - BucketName : !ImportValue 'ArtifactStore'
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Cloudformation didn't support dynamic default value. It's not possible to have a dynamic default value for CloudFormation. As the template has not executed at the time all parameters are being collected. However, you can use SSM parameter for as the workaround, something like below.

```
Parameters
    PagerDutyUrl:
        Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
        Description: The Pagerduty url
```

Going back to your current cloudformation, I am thinking that value ${fmMainVpc} might not be initialized correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I didn't get "value ${fmMainVpc} might not be initialized correctly", can you elaborate, this could help me in fixing the issue. I created a simple test.`AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters :
  StageFrmSSM :
    Type : 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>'
    Default: PParamName001

Resources:

  StageName:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Description: Fields manager database name - dev
      Name: PParamName002
      Type: String
      Default: !Ref StageFrmSSM
`

Comment: the test passed validation but failed with message  Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/}: [Default]]

Comment: _Not initialized correctly_ - I had a similar issue and it turned out I had mismatched lower and uppercase characters in my parameter name!

Comment: I have the same issue, I noticed the same, misspelled the parameter key in yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm my case, I had the follow resource:

```
          # removed for brevity
          Subnets:
            - !ImportValue: parent-stack-subnet-a
            - !ImportValue: parent-stack-subnet-b
```

I forgot to remove the `:` when changing the syntax from `Fn::ImportValue` to the shorthand `!ImportValue`. Confusing error message, but removing the `:` resolved it because that was incorrect usage on my part.