# YAML Syntax for ImportValue into CFN Parameter Default

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm struggling with the YAML syntax to import a value that was exported by another CFN stack into the default value of a parameter in a new stack.

What I have at the moment is:

```
Parameters:
  DBEndpoint:
    Description: Hostname endpoint for RDS Database
    Type: String
    Default: Fn::ImportValue: 'db-endpoint'
```

Where `db-endpoint` is the value exported by the following YAML template snippet:

```
Outputs:
  dbhost:
    Description: "RDS Endpoint Address"
    Value: !GetAtt DB.Endpoint.Address
    Export:
      Name: db-endpoint
```

The export works fine, but  I get a parse error (`Template format error: YAML not well-formed.` ) when trying to load the template with the `ImportValue` line.

---

Update:

I have the YAML parsing correctly now, I think, but now get a new error.

With

```
Parameters:
  DBEndpoint:
    Description: Hostname endpoint for RDS Database
    Type: String
    Default: !ImportValue 'db-endpoint'
```

I get an error `Template format error: Every Default member must be a string.`.

So, it seems closer, but still not working.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52240826) implies this might not even be possible... is that the case?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that and what else you can do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!ImportValue 'db-endpoint'` **can't** be used in `Parameters`. It can only be used in `Resources` and `Outputs` of your template. You have to "manually" (aka, outside of CloudFormation, e.g. by a wrapper script) set the default value of `DBEndpoint` to the actual value of your `db-endpoint`.

Comment: It's a shame it can't be used in `Parameters` as it would be useful have the option to change it when building from the template. I have just used the `ImportValue` in my `userdata` directly instead - which works perfectly but is obviously a bit less flexible.